# Can't figure out the Logic and Syntax to create this list

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Given the below edmx file, I am trying to write an asynchronous ActionResult that will give me a list of all scenarios that have not been played by any of the User's Characters.  I am trying to figure out the most efficient way and also the logic to get the list of scenarios to my view.  I am new to Linq and to MVC so this has been challenging.

[image: EDMX file]

My Current Try at the ActionResult is found below:

```
    // GET: Home/ChooseScenario
    public async Task<ActionResult> ChooseScenario(string charId)
    {
        //Convert passed in charId string to related Character object 
        var pFSCharacter = await db.PFSCharacters
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.PFSCHARACTERID == charId);

        //Initialize empty list of Characters for the User 
        List<PFSCharacter> userCharacters = new List<PFSCharacter>();

        //determine if the pFSCharacter is Core and only give me back a list of characters for the user that are core as well 
        if (pFSCharacter.IsCore)
        {
            userCharacters = await db.PFSCharacters
                .Where(x => x.PFSUSERID == User.Identity.GetUserId() && x.IsCore == true)
                .ToListAsync();
        }
        //If pFSCharacter is not core give me back a list of characters for the user that are not core
        else
        {
            userCharacters = await db.PFSCharacters
                .Where(x => x.PFSUSERID == User.Identity.GetUserId() && x.IsCore == false)
                .ToListAsync();
        }

        List<PFSCharacterScenario> pFSCharacterScenarios = new List<PFSCharacterScenario>();

        //try to figure out the list of Scenarios that none of the User's characters have already participated in
        foreach (PFSCharacter character in userCharacters)
        {
            //can this be done better or in a different way that a foreach loop?
            //can't figure out the logic to give back list of scenarios that each character has not played yet

            //pFSScenarios = await db.PFSCharacterScenarios  //this will overwrite the list need to add to the 
                                                             //list already started for the other characters on 
                                                             //previous loops

            //.ToListAsync();
        }

        //need to remove duplicates scenarios from list so scenario only appears once. 

        //pair down list even further to scenarios that pFSCharacter.charLevel >= pFSScenario.minLevel 
        //and pFSCharacter.charLevel <= pFSScenario.maxLevel


        //var pFSScenarios = db.PFSScenarios
        //    .Include(p => p.PFSFirstSubmittedBy)
        //    .Include(p => p.PFSScenarioType)
        //    .Where(p => p.IsActive == true)

        //    .OrderBy(p => p.PFSSCENARIOTYPEID)
        //    .ThenBy(p => p.Season)
        //    .ThenBy(p => p.SeasonID)
        //    .ThenBy(p => p.MinLevel)
        //    .ThenBy(p => p.ScenarioName);

        //pass pFSCharacter to View to pass to next Controller ActionResult
        ViewBag.Character = pFSCharacter;

        //send list of scenarios to the View to be displayed.
        return View(await pFSScenarios);
    }
```

EDIT: I worked out, with a friend, the SQL Query that I need to use.  What is the best way to get it into my controller using LINQ?

```
SELECT *
FROM PFSScenarios
Where PFSSCENARIOID NOT IN (

Select s.PFSSCENARIOID
FROM PFSScenarios s
Inner Join PFSCharacterScenarios cs
    on s.PFSSCENARIOID = cs.PFSSCENARIOID
Inner Join PFSCharacters c
    on c.PFSCHARACTERID = cs.PFSCHARACTERID
WHERE C.PFSUSERID = '35be8bbb-99dc-44bc-9d84-9bcc937d79d6'
)
```

EDIT3:  Getting close, however still getting error

`Unable to create a constant value of type 'PFSScenarioTracker.Data.EF.PFSCharacter'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.`

when using Fabio Luz solution below.

The Error disappears if I use the blank `List<PFSCharacter> userCharacters = new List<PFSCharacter>();` and comment out the `if/else statement` populating userCharacters, however then it returns every scenario in the DB that doesn't fit the other criteria I added `i => i.IsActive == true && i.MinLevel <= pFSCharacter.CharLevel && i.MaxLevel >= pFSCharacter.CharLevel &&`.

Here is my current Controller Action Result:

```
    // GET: Home/ChooseScenario
    public async Task<ActionResult> ChooseScenario(string charId)
    {
        string currentUser = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        //Convert passed in charId string to related Character object 
        var pFSCharacter = await db.PFSCharacters
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.PFSCHARACTERID == charId);

        List<PFSCharacter> userCharacters = new List<PFSCharacter>();

        //List<PFSScenario> pFSScenarios = new List<PFSScenario>();
        //determine if the pFSCharacter is Core and only give me back a list of characters for the user that are core as well 
        if (pFSCharacter.IsCore)
        {
            userCharacters = await db.PFSCharacters
                .Where(x => x.PFSUSERID == currentUser && x.IsCore == true)
                .ToListAsync();
        }
        //If pFSCharacter is not core give me back a list of characters for the user that are not core
        else
        {
            userCharacters = await db.PFSCharacters
                .Where(x => x.PFSUSERID == currentUser && x.IsCore == false)
                .ToListAsync();
        }

        var pFSScenarios = await db.PFSScenarios.Where(i => i.IsActive == true && i.MinLevel <= pFSCharacter.CharLevel && i.MaxLevel >= pFSCharacter.CharLevel && !i.PFSCharacterScenarios.Any(x => userCharacters.Contains(x.PFSCharacter))).ToListAsync();

        //pass pFSCharacter to View to pass to next Controller ActionResult
        ViewBag.Character = pFSCharacter;

        //send list of scenarios to the View to be displayed.
        return View(pFSScenarios);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a list of all scenarios that have not been played by any of the User's Characters:

```
//this returns all scenarios that have not been played by any of the Users
var scenarios = await db.PFSScenarios.Where(i => i.PFSCharacterScenarios.Any()).ToListAsync();
```

**Edit**

```
//this returns all scenarios that have not been played by any of the User's Chars
var scenarios = await db.PFSScenarios.Where(i => !i.PFSCharacterScenarios.Any(x => userCharacters.Contains(x.PSFCharacter))).ToListAsync();
```

I'm not familiar with your model, not sure if it's correct. What I'm trying to say is "use navigation properties", I think they will solve your problem.

Comment: Please avoid `.Count() < 1` and rather do `!.Any()`, as the former will iterate the whole collection whereas the latter stops with the first item found ...

Comment: In general when using linq to objects Any is almost always faster, however when using Linq to entities Count() > 0 can be faster, purely it seems because of the often convoluted SQL generated by EF

Comment: wanting to confirm that `z =>.PFSCHARACTERID` was supposed to be `z => z.PFSCHARACTERID`

Comment: Just tried to implement this and got 

`Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of type 'PFSScenarioTracker.Data.EF.PFSCharacter'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.`

Comment: @Fabio tried your solution still getting an error.  I think it has something to do with my If/Else statement above.

Comment: @shaun debug your code and make sure what line is throwing the exception, then we can proceed

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Fabio I was able to get the list to come up correctly for players using this for my controller:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> ChooseScenario(string charId)
    {
        string currentUser = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        //Convert passed in charId string to related Character object 
        var pFSCharacter = await db.PFSCharacters
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.PFSCHARACTERID == charId);

        var pFSScenarios = await db.PFSScenarios
            .Where(
                i => i.IsActive == true &&
                i.MinLevel <= pFSCharacter.CharLevel && 
                i.MaxLevel >= pFSCharacter.CharLevel &&
                !i.PFSCharacterScenarios
                .Any(
                    x => x.PFSCharacter.IsCore == pFSCharacter.IsCore &&
                    x.PFSCharacter.PFSUser.PFSUSERID == currentUser))
                .ToListAsync();

        //pass pFSCharacter to View to pass to next Controller ActionResult
        ViewBag.Character = pFSCharacter;

        //send list of scenarios to the View to be displayed.
        return View(pFSScenarios);
    }
```

Got rid of the If/Else statement and used the .any to look for the USER ID of the current logged in user for any of the characters currently in the PFSCharacterScenarios table.